# Can the ValuesController class be renamed on ASP.net project?

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

I'm new to C#/ASP.net development, so bear that in mind.  I'm following this

example: https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-backend-asp-core/

This produces a file in Controllers/ called ValuesController.cs. It contains a class called ValuesController with a number of public methods. When I run the code in the debugger, it successfully handles HTTP requests to https://localhost:44315/api/values.  So then I tried renaming the ValuesController to ValuesController2 (and I even tried renaming the .cs file).  But the code only works when this class is named ValuesController.  My question is: is this hardcoded in ASP.net somewhere?  If it is, I can find no documentation of it. If it isn't, I can't explain this strange behavior.

Comment: The documentation [describes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api) how the system selects which controller to use, with more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection).

Answer (score 1):

All controller names should end in `Controller` by convention.

There isn't any problem if you rename it into `Values2Controller`. Just make sure it has the `Controller` suffix.

Your URLs should also change from `api/values` to `api/values2`.

Comment: I tried to name the controller Values2Controller, and it didn't work either, not even when the file it was in was named Values2Controller.cs.  The controller must be named ValuesController. Why would that be?  There is no reference to ValuesController anywhere in my code.

Comment: What exactly did not work? You couldn't hit any controller action? If not, you also have to change the URLs from `https://localhost:44315/api/values` to `https://localhost:44315/api/values2`

Comment: @GusMueller We use Web API all the time. I can assure you that we have no controllers called "ValuesController" in our code, and plenty with other names.

Comment: It wasn't intuitive what the problem was, by Ciubotariu Florin gets the prize for pointing me in the right direction.  It seems that when the class is named ValuesController and the route decorator (is that what this is?) is [Route("api/[controller]")] then https://localhost:44315/api/values goes to ValuesController.  When all else is the same but the controller is named Values2Controller, then the url is https://localhost:44315/api/values.  It looks like the mapping of routes to controllers is highly-opinionated in a way that I did not expect.

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved the issue. Can you mark my answer as 'correct' in case it helped you?

Comment: @GusMueller Your comment implies that renaming `ValuesController` to `Values2Controller` **did not** cause the route to change from `api/values/` to `api/values2/` - is that correct? Because if so, there's something else going on here.

Comment: no Ian -- changing the url to api/values2/ works as you said. i just didn't know how precisely endpoints were automagically mapped onto controllers (and the example i was following didn't really explain). i don't think i can upvote or say an answer is correct because i am such a noob on stackoverflow (at least with this login)